# Connect 4 Game - End Condition

Tags: javascript

I am building a connect 4 web app with javascript. I am currently trying to create an 'end game' check where if the entire grid is filled and there is no winner, the game will end.

```
function endGame(yTarget, xTarget) {
  let topRowOpen = true;

  // must have all yTarget index to have class for game to end

  for (let i = 0; i < yTarget + 1; i++) {
    let box = $(`#g-${i}-${0}`);
    console.log(box)
    if (box.hasClass("selectedP0Box") || box.hasClass("selectedP1Box")) {
      topRowOpen = false;
    }
  }
  return !topRowOpen;
}
```

I can't seem to figure this out using a for loop (which I need to allow for differently sized game boards).

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the entire board and check if it is filled? Also, can you explain what yTarget and xTarget are?

Comment: `${0}` ??? can a  0 be a variable identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Here's more something that you're looking for:

```
var moveAvailable = function() {
    var n = 0;
    while (true) {
        var topCell = $('g-' + (n++) + '-0');
        if (!topCell.length) break;

        // It's important to use &&, not || here:
        if (!topCell.hasClass('selectedP0Box')
            && !topCell.hasClass('selectedP1Box')) return true;
    }

    // All top cells were checked; none were empty
    return false;
}
```

(Note: my jquery is pretty rusty, I'm sure you could make this code look much nicer)